# typescript (error TS2322) : Type '{ type: ErrorPageType; }' is not assignable to type 'ErrorPageType.SIGNUP'

Tags: javascript, typescript

New to TS and am trying to create a Type which can then be passed as a prop from another component into this one like : `<Error type={ErrorPageType.GENERIC}/>`  to conditionally render the correct view. Here is my code:

```
export enum ErrorPageType {
        ACCESS = "access",
        GENERIC = "generic",
    }

interface ErrorProps {
    type?: ErrorPageType;
}

const getErrorType = (type?: ErrorPageType) {
    switch (type) {
        case ErrorPageType.ACCESS:
            return <AccessErrorPage />;
        case ErrorPageType.GENERIC:
            return <GenericErrorPage />;
        default:
            return <GenericErrorPage />;
    }
}

const ErrorPage = (type?: ErrorProps) => {
    return getErrorType(type)
};


export default ErrorPage;
```

I am getting the error: `error TS2322: Type '{ type: ErrorPageType; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & ErrorPageType.ACCESS) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ErrorPageType.FSSO) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ErrorPageType.GENERIC) | (IntrinsicAttributes & ErrorPageType.SIGNUP)'. Type '{ type: ErrorPageType; }' is not assignable to type 'ErrorPageType.SIGNUP'.` and I am not really sure why. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ErrorPage` function is getting an `ErrorProps` type value as the input. You can’t pass that directly to `getErrorType` function since it is expecting an `ErrorPageType` type input.

You should modify like this:

```
const ErrorPage = (type?: ErrorProps) => {
    return getErrorType(type?.type)
};
```

Comment: that got me to a new error on this line: `return getErrorType(type.type);` <== `object is possibly undefined` which is progress lol. again, I'm new to TS - but aren't i making that param optional? so why would I get an error that it might be undefined if it isn't even required

Comment: I updated my answer to allow optional type. The reason is since you define the function like “type?: ErrorProps“, your “type” can be null. So we have to consider null type as well which I forgot in my answer.

Comment: you're a lifesaver! Spent way too much time banging my head against the wall. Could you maybe explain why i needed to dig into `type` and make it `type.type`? My assumption is when I pass `<ErrorPage type={'ErrorPageType.GENERIC'} />` .. then in the ErrorPAgComponent (above) validatesit's value agains what is defined in the `enum`? But it seems like defining `(type?: ErrorPageType;)` in the interface actually _assigns_ an obj (`ErrorPageType{}`) to the prop `type`? so it looks like `type: {type: ErrorPageType }` --- is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Assigning `type` inside the interface defines a structure of an object which has `type` property of `ErrorPageType`.